# Why changing random number generator changes running time of quick sort in C

Tags: c, quicksort

I'm written a quick sort implementation in C. Changing the rand function range(using the remainder) in the first loop changes the running time of the algorithm dramatically. As it is right now, the algorithm takes 43 seconds. Changing the range from 100 to 10000 reduces the running to 0.9 seconds.

Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void quick_sort(int array[], int low, int high);
int partition(int array[], int low, int high);
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}


int main(void)
{
    const int len = 1000000;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int array[len];

    puts("Populating the array...\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        array[i] = rand() % 100; // Changing this line dramatically reduce the running time

    puts("|Now sorting the array...|\n");

    quick_sort(array, 0, len-1);

    /*for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)*/
        /*printf("%d ", array[i]);*/
}


void quick_sort(int array[], int low, int high)
{
    int j;

    if(low < high)
    {
        j = partition(array, low, high);
        quick_sort(array, low, j-1);
        quick_sort(array, j+1, high);
    }
}

int partition(int array[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot    = array[high];
    int leftwall = low-1;

    for(int i = low; i < high; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] <= pivot)
        {
            ++leftwall;
            swap(&array[leftwall], &array[i]);
        }
    }

    swap(&array[leftwall+1], &array[high]);

    return ++leftwall;
}
```

Comment: What platform / compiler? Can't reproduce with gcc on ubuntu. (Takes same time)

Comment: Mine was similar difference. Perhpas it tells you it's the wrong algorithm to use when you have 1000000 elements with only 100 different values.

Comment: I'm impressed that you managed to shove ~4MB of automatic vars into `main()`. A fair number of platforms that would puke in itself.

Comment: @WhozCraig I had to change that in my test!

Comment: @user1320881 I'm using Elementary OS freya. gcc 4.8.4

Comment: The library function `qsort` has the timing the other way round, but not much difference between the two mod values. It was almost 10 times quicker than your quickest. Perhaps your algorithm isn't right although it *did* sort correctly.

Comment: @WeatherVane I guess you're right. I'm learning sorting algorithms right now, and I haven't read anything about this issue so I got curious.

Comment: For one thing: don't call a function for a trivial swap.

Comment: @WeatherVane Lol. I always test all the algorithm I learn on 1 million integers. I'm using a two year old Pentium laptop :)

Comment: @MAA there are two popular quicksort algorithms, the simple "sweep" algorithm which you have here (very easy to code and understand), and the "squeeze" algorithm. You already know how the former works. The latter works by taking two indicies, high and low, and essentially doing what you're doing here, but on *both* ends of the partition in a single pass. The result is *generally* significantly fewer swaps, particularly when there is significant replicate data in the sequence. Maybe look at other quicksort options.  And btw, `qsort` is almost *never* just quicksort.

Comment: ... the lib api often employs refinements for small-partition sorting that cache super-well, such as introsort or insertion sort, In many lib versions partitions smaller than, say, 16 elements, are subjected to a completely unrolled introsort or swap-network that is just stupid-fast.

Comment: @MAA just by putting `swap` action inline knocked more than one third off the execution time of your slow one.

Comment: @WeatherVane removing the function did improve the speed. from 40s to 30s.

Comment: One more thing. If this were truly a strict-range of [0..99], you would be better off using a [*counting sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). For small, fixed range sequences, it is near-impossible to beat for time. [example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b57668aa62b4800)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that when partitioning the array you end up moving a large number of duplicate values. When you pick the random numbers from only 100 choices, the array of a million elements will have about 10,000 of each value. It looks like you'll be swapping them around every call to  `partition` due to the `array[i] <= pivot` comparison. For example, when you are almost done and a partition has only two distinct values in it, it still has about 20,000 elements…

Comment: I think the answer is somewhere along these lines too. I'm too new at this to know for sure though